# Web SQL not working from local file system, how can I run without any server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-sql

After updated the chrome browser the WebSQL not working from local files, but it is working from server like IIS,Xampp or other. How can I Access the webSQL without using server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way as latest updates of chrome and opera have put a restriction on code accessing client-side websql database to be accessible from server hosted code only

Comment: But I run previously.

Comment: In earlier versions of chrome and opera there was no such restriction

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug.

See [Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=618381&q=websql&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

It is  fixed in currently available Beta Chrome version ( 52.0.2743.60 beta-m ).

You can also use Safari browser, which have a pretty safe implementation of WebSql API.